# Append dataframe to start of a list

Tags: r, list

I have 1 list A containing 2 vectors and 1 vector B. I want to insert B into A such that B is in the first position.

I have this:

```
A <- list(LETTERS, letters)
B <- 1:10
```

I want this:

```
A <- list(B, A[[1]], A[[2]])
```

I currently do this:

```
B <- list(B)    
for (i in 1:length(A)) {
    B[i+1] <- A[[i]]}
```

Is there a better way without using `for` loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `c` :

```
c(list(B), A)
```

Comment: Thanks. Learnt another use for `c`.